# Upvoting interesting or seems useful answer, without knowing its accuracy

Tags: discussion

So, I've been upvoting several answers and questions that catch my interest, mainly because:

- it's well written
- the topic shares my interest
- it might be helpful to me in the future - yes, I know there's favorite feature for that

Then I stop and look back on the upvote button

> This question show research effort; it is useful and clear

Some of the answers are for linux, which is not my expertise, but I see them provide a creative way to solve the problem. I do not know if it works, or it is just plainly wrong.

So, have I been doing the upvotes all wrong?

Comment: "it is useful" You find it useful according to your criteria so an upvote is fine.

Comment: "So, have I been doing the upvotes all wrong?" - You can issue a vote, any vote, for any reason.  You don't have to justify your vote to anyone.  However, the one thing you cannot do, is perform targeted voting  specifically because it was submitted by someone specific.  In other words don't serial vote anyone's contributions because they are somebody specific